# Protect external hard disk by password- batch file

Tags: batch-file, passwords, hard-drive, usb-drive

I want to protect my external hard disk (USB connecting) by asking password when the hard disk inserted to the computer- to any computer with any Windows OS version.

I don't want to make it by 3rd party software because I don't want to encrypt the data- just add password (for prevent reconstruction problems in the future).

So I thought to create batch file that will fired automatically when the external hard disk inserted into the computer and do the following steps:

1. ask the user password.
2. compare to the correct password.
3. if the user enter wrong password- eject the external hard disk safely.

I don't know well batch file commands, and I understood that `autorun` files don't work in Windows7 and up.

So, may can anyone help me to write the nessecary commands and tell me how to cause that file to fired automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make it robust with a batch file.

Any code you use with a batch cript can be closed, stopped, bypassed, and the password read.

Comment: All of what foxdrive said is correct.  The only way to do this would be through a 3rd party program, if there is even one that exists.  In about an hour (am currently in school), I will post the batch script you are asking for, just in case you still want it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am home from school now, and will put up the simple batch script.

```
@echo off
cls
set PASSWORD=1234
set /P USERINPUT=Please Enter your password: %=%
if %USERINPUT% EQU %PASSWORD% (
    goto correct
) else (
    goto incorrect
)
:correct
exit
:incorrect
REM Eject hard drive safely
exit
```

You can change the password to anything you like, and will need to replace my comment (for ejecting the hard drive) with the proper command.  I personally do not know how to do this.

BurnE